# Program crashes when deleting a pointer pointing to the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers

If I go...

```
int *foo = new int;  
foo += 1; 
delete foo;
```

Most of the time it crashes. Is there a reason for this?  I'm trying to have the pointer point one spot forward (4 bytes).  Thanks.

Edit (six months later): This was the first question I asked on SO, and it was a silly question and deserved the downvotes.  It can be deleted if it's of no use to learners.  I was indeed talking about allocating an int of four bytes on the heap, then moving the pointer four bytes forward, and then deleting the int pointer, essentially deleting God knows what, leading to undefined behaviour.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What would you expect this code to do?

Comment: You're deleting a pointer to a (probably) non-allocated memory address; of course it's going to crash.

Comment: I learned that after every "new" you have to use a "delete", so does that mean if you allocate memory on the heap you can't move the pointer?  Or would making it a null pointer before deleting it be the answer?

Comment: @GoBusto when you say "of course" you assume that every one knows why it happens, the question is not bad and in my opinion doesn't deserve down vote.

Comment: @OopsUser The funny thing is it doesn't even have to crash, so "of course" does not apply.

Comment: @OopsUser For the record, I have neither up- nor down-voted this question; It seems like an honest enough enquiry. I'm just surprised that anyone could *not* expect arbitrary address `delete`ions to cause problems. A *valid* address is allocated, the pointer storing that address is changed, and then that (probably-no-longer-valid) address is deleted. To my mind, this is much like buying house number 6 and then being surprised that your neighbours get annoyed when you try to sell house number 8.

Comment: @Gobusto Asker thinks that the variable is passed to `delete` rather than the value held by that variable. An easy enough misconception for a novice.

Comment: I don't get why people are downvoting this. This is an eye-opening question.

Comment: @zenith Probably because the question text does not make it clear that the asker is thinking in terms of the *variable name* rather than the address. The way I read it is: "I allocate one address and then delete a completely different address, why does it crash?" Perhaps the question text could be re-phrased to emphasize that the OP is not thinking in terms of *addresses*, but in terms of *named, source-code variables* - this would clarify where the confusion lies (reduce the confusion about the confusion, as it were).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must pass to `delete` the value that `new` returned. You don't do that.

I think that you are confused as to what you are passing to `delete`. I think that you believe that `delete foo` will delete the memory associated with the variable. It doesn't. It deletes the memory whose address is stored in `foo`.

As an example, this is legitimate:

```
int* foo = new int;
int* bar = foo;
delete bar;
```

What matters is not the name of the variable, but rather the value of the variable.

Here's another example:

```
int* arr = new int[10];
int* ptr = arr;
for (int i; i < 10; i++)
{
    *ptr = i;
    ptr++;
}
delete[] arr;
```

In order to perform pointer arithmetic, and retain the address returned by `new[]`, we introduced an extra variable. I used an array because it doesn't make sense to perform arithmetic on a pointer to a single value.

Note that in the code above, it could be written more clearly using `arr[i] = i` and so avoid the need for a second pointer variable. I wrote it as above to illustrate how you might code when pointer arithmetic is the right option.

Comment: So does that mean I have to point it to exactly the same place before I delete it?  Or is moving pointers something that's not done?

Comment: @TitoneMaurice You can move pointers, but you probably want to have one pointer that will always point to the memory that you need to delete. You could for example assign another pointer based on the value of `foo`.

Comment: I've added a couple of examples to hopefully shed some light. Pointer arithmetic is done, but typically you'd keep a copy of the address returned by new.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  So if you're going to move pointers around you gotta keep the original spot, at least on the heap, gotcha.

Comment: The value you pass to `delete` must. Be the value returned by `new`. Various ways to achieve that, but that's the rule you must follow.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing you can safely pass to `delete` is something you got when you called `new`, or `nullptr`, in that case the `delete` won't do anything.

You changed the value of the pointer - therefore it isn't "something you got when you called `new`"