# C language. free() and changed pointer

Tags: c, free

Will `free()` work correctly if I change pointer the following way?

```
ar_byte_100=calloc(100,1);
ar_byte_100=&((unsigned long int*)ar_byte_100)[50];
free(ar_byte_100);
```

Comment: Nope(or might as it invokes UB). You have to give `free` the pointer returned by `calloc`.

Comment: A similar question, regarding C++ rather than C: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29192430/4200092

Comment: @GoBusto IMHO, No need to go for `C++` here, lots of `C` dupes are already there. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

You must pass the exact pointer returned by `malloc()` or `calloc()` to `free()`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard `free(ptr)`

`ptr` should be a pointer returned by `malloc()` `calloc()` and `realloc()` anything other than that is a undefined behavior.

Comment: And can I `realloc(ar_byte_100, 0); ar_byte_100=&((unsigned long int*)ar_byte_100)[-50];realloc(ar_byte_100, 0);`?